# jupyter python notebook showing kernel error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I am accessing jupyterhub notebook through browser as it is running on a remote server(using nginx so that jupyterhub is accessible to client machines).When I access the notebook a kernel error is shown at the top of the screen. Jupyterhub and jupyter notebook is running on a kubernetes cluster and the jupyter notebook is a custom built docker image suitable for python programming. I am very new into python/jupyter hub/notebook, please suggest how to resolve the kernel error.[image]

Comment: If you click on the "Kernel error" it should show a log. Could you please post the error log?

Comment: on clicking on the kernel error it says, failed to start the kernel. not found. And when i do ´jupyter kernel spec list´ , I get the following response:Available kernels: python3    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3. Following are the content of my kernel.json file {
 "display_name": "python3",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python3",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ]
}. python3 is present in the path mentioned in the kernel.json file. I am running jupyterhub and notebook on a kubernetes cluster which is setup on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @alec_djinn can you plz help?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't without a proper error log. If that is the only info you have I don't know where to start. You can set a bounty (probably you don't have this right yet) to attract more attention to this post. Hopefully someone more skilled than me can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Please check `kernel.json` file, check if the path to the `Python` executable is correct

for example my `kernel.json` looks like this, in my case the Python binary is located at
`C:/Users/Vinod/Anaconda/envs/env_name/python`

Check the path in your case

```
{
 "argv": [
  "C:/Users/Vinod/Anaconda/envs/env_name/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Note: env_name refers to the anaconda environment you are using

Answer (score 0):

you should use this command

> jupyter kernelspec remove python3

python3 is name of kernel at my end, it can be yours.
after than run jupyter notebook again from command prompt.